# Append dynamically generated string to end of CSV line

Tags: php, csv, append, fputcsv

So I've got two CSV's: InputCSV and OutputCSV

InputCSV.csv

```
name     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5
john     qOJY     OHXl     vIOH     Tdnm     Z7OH
greg     YRc1     hyFB     pW8m     5LSE     Yo4r
saly     Dy4o     51Ui     tuKI     02VQ     RVgB
```

---

OutputCSV.csv

```
name     url
john     site.com/JcRIeyFCEl.mp4
greg     site.com/TTwF4Cue2B.mp4
saly     site.com/ouroANTtAC.mp4
```

---

So in processor.php, I have

```
    if (($csvFile = fopen("InputCSV.csv", "r")) !== false && ($resultCsv = fopen("OutputCSV.csv", 'w')) !== false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== false) {
            // do stuff to generate $thumbfile
            // this bit needs to use parts of $data like $data[3], $data[5] to generate $thumbfile
            // which in the end should look like $thumbfile = 'site.com/rAndOmsTRing.jpg';
        }
    $outputData = fgetcsv($resultCsv);
    $outputData[] .= $thumbfile_url; //Append to end of line. is this what I'm doing wrong? 
    fputcsv($resultCsv, $outputData);
```

What I need this to do is add a new column to OutputCSV.csv, and append $thumbfile at the end of each line/row. At the moment, what this does is it removes the two existing columns, and writes in only $thumbfile as just one column.

OutputCSV.csv needs to look like so after this script runs:
OutputCSV.csv

```
name     url                         thumbfile
john     site.com/JcRIeyFCEl.mp4     site.com/snTflxaqNI.jpg
greg     site.com/TTwF4Cue2B.mp4     site.com/ELrg6vwKEr.jpg
saly     site.com/ouroANTtAC.mp4     site.com/xTjfqCEoIZ.jpg
```

NOTE: the actual csv's I'm using don't have headings. I only put them there to help make easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

to make what you need, you woul need to save the data of OutputCSV.csv in array, then in the same array add your $thumbfile.

here an example, i use your csv file separated by ",".

```
    if (($csvFile = fopen("InputCSV.csv", "r")) !== false && ($resultCsv = fopen("OutputCSV.csv", 'r')) !== false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($csvFile,4096,",")) !== false) {
        // do stuff to generate $thumbfile
        $thumbfile[]=$data[3].$data[5].".jpg";
            }
        $x=0;
        while (($dataoutput = fgetcsv($resultCsv,4096,",")) !== false) {
            $dataotputcsv[$x]=$dataoutput;   //here is [0]=> "john" [1]=> "site.com/JcRIeyFCEl.mp4"
            array_push($dataotputcsv[$x], $thumbfile[$x]);  //here i add the $thumbfile
      //and now is [0]=> "john" [1]=> "site.com/JcRIeyFCEl.mp4" [2]=> "vIOHZ7OH.jpg"
        $x++;
        }
        $file = fopen("OutputCSV.csv", 'w'); 
        foreach($dataotputcsv as $string) {
            fputcsv($file, $string);  //save all lines to file
        }

    }
```